# $\operatorname{rowspace}(A) = \operatorname{rowspace}(A^T A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be any rectangular real matrix. I presume that the following is a standard result in linear algebra:

$$\operatorname{rowspace}(A) = \operatorname{rowspace}(A^T A)$$

Where can I find a proof of this?

This is not a homework exercise. I just ran into this question while doing some other computations and realized I wasn't able to find it in my linear algebra textbooks.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show few elementary steps?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I can show easily that $\mathbf{v} \in \operatorname{rowspace}(\mathbb{A}^{\top}\mathbb{A})$ implies $\mathbf{v} \in \operatorname{rowspace}(\mathbb{A})$. But for the other way I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Is this statement true for *any* rectangular matrix? Or we need $\mathbb{A}$ to be full rank or something?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215145/rank-of-product-of-a-matrix-and-its-transpose/682249, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-operatornamerankata-operatornameranka-for-any-a-in-m-m-times-n

Comment: I think you essentially have the proof there: one is contained in the other, and by the linked posts the dimensions are the same (take transposes to translate them into ranks, if need be)?

Comment: @prets You're saying that if $A,B$ are vector spaces of the *same dimension*, with $A \subset B$, then $A = B$ ?

Comment: Absolutely. An $n$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional space fills up the entire space.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Though I'd still like to see a "textbook" proof of this. Feels like an elementary fact.

Comment: See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272572/).